# Redactor Rails - How to save content to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text-editor, rich-text-editor, redactor

For my application, I am trying to implement a rich text editor to "Projects" made by "Users"

Right now, I am trying to implement Redactor Rails (https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails). I followed the process below.

**Question 1:** How can I go about re-installing with the devise option?

**Question 2:** I have created a t.text "description" under Projects in my data table. And my Project form right now uses Simple Form. I see the text editor, but how do I save what is entered into the text editor field after submit is pressed?

```
gem 'redactor-rails'
$ bundle install
$ gem install redactor-rails
```

Added to application.js:

```
//= require redactor-rails
```

Added to application.css:

```
*= require redactor-rails
```

And then, dropped in the following line to my individual "Projects" :

```
<%= text_area_tag :editor, "", :class => "redactor", :rows => 40, :cols => 120 %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use *raw* `text_area_tag` method. You should use simple_form API methods. Here is an example (in Slim, but you should get the idea):

```
= simple_form_for(comment) do |f|

  = f.input :content, input_html: { class: 'redactor', rows: '4' }

  = f.button :submit
```

Next. Redactor does not clean user's input. You should do it manually.

Controller code (create action in particular) example:

```
class CommentsController
  # used for sanitization user's input
  REDACTOR_TAGS = %w(code span div label a br p b i del strike u img video audio
                  iframe object embed param blockquote mark cite small ul ol li
                  hr dl dt dd sup sub big pre code figure figcaption strong em
                  table tr td th tbody thead tfoot h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6)
  REDACTOR_ATTRIBUTES = %w(href)

  # ...

  def create
    params[:comment][:content] = sanitize_redactor(params[:comment][:content])

    comment = Comment.create(params[:comment])

    if comment.save
      # ...
    end
  end

  # ...

  private

  def sanitize_redactor(orig_text)
    stripped = view_context.strip_tags(orig_text)
    if stripped.present? # this prevents from creating empty comments
      view_context.sanitize(orig_text, tags: REDACTOR_TAGS, attributes: REDACTOR_ATTRIBUTES)
    else
      nil
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: Can you help me understand why we need to clean/sanitize user's input?

Comment: That's because your application waits for the params named in common way. In my example content of comment should come to my CommentsController as params[:comment][:content] (it gets from name attribute of the input field). When you use simple text_area_tag you should set the name of the input by yourself.

Comment: We need to sanitize user's input to prevent different kinds of hacker attacks, XSS in particular (when attacker inserts javascript code inside your page). Please, google about XSS attacks.

Comment: So I followed your f.input for the redactor, but when I call it, project.content, it comes out not in the format that was submitted in, how can this be fixed?

Comment: So I updated blogupdates_controller.rb as you mentioned and get NameError for: "sanitize_redactor":: def create
    params[:blogupdate][:content] = sanitize_redactor(params[:blogupdate][:content])
   [at]project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    [at]blogupdate = @project.blogupdates.create!(params[:blogupdate])
    redirect_to [at]blogupdate.project
  end

Answer (score 1):

For those out there who are not using simple_form, this also works:

```
<div class="redactor_box">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Content goes here...", :class => "redactor"%>
</div>
```